# How to prove the theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I know how to prove the theorem in continuous cases, but how to prove it in the continuous in $E$ relative to $E$ condition?
THANKS!

[image]

Comment: What does "continuous in $E$ relative to $E$" mean? Never seen taht terminology before.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have added the definition of that in the new version. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compactness is an absolute property.  If $K$ is a subset of a topological space $X$ and $X\subseteq Y$, then $K$ is compact in $X$ iff $K$ is compact in $Y$.

Comment: What is $Y$ here?

Comment: A topological space in which X is included.